# How to access Kinesis ApproximateArrivalTime in AWS Lambda expression

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to access the [ApproximateArrivalTimestamp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_Record.html) field of a Kinesis data record from within an AWS Lambda. The field was added back in [September](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3262).

I see that the ApproximateArrivalTime field is optional. In my Lambda I am outputting a list of all available fields. I see the three required (data, partitionKey, sequenceNumber) but not ApproximateArrivalTime.

Any idea how I can access this, or how I can set it in the Kinesis stream?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this field is not yet available in Lambda. It should be available sometime this month or next month.